# Why does top()'s return value change after calling pop()?

Tags: c++, auto, const-reference

The const reference returned by `priority_queue`'s `top()` changes after calling `pop()` (visual studio 2015)

```
priority_queue<int> queue;
queue.push(1);
queue.push(2);
queue.push(3);

const int & m = queue.top();
cout << m << endl; // 3
queue.pop();
cout << m << endl; // 2
queue.pop();
cout << m << endl; // 1
```

If get top value by `auto & m = queue.top();`, then output is also `3 2 1`.

While if get top value by `auto m = queue.top();`, then output is `3 3 3`.

What's mechanism behind this ?

Comment: Undefined behaviour, you have created a reference to an element that no longer exists.

Comment: not sure why this is downvoted, seems like a fair enough question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If get top value by `auto & m = queue.top();`, then output is also `3 2 1`.

Despite it is calling undefined behavior to use `m` after the 1st `pop()` call, it is likely that the next value is moved to that dangling reference (address). That is because the default underlying type of [`std::priority_queue`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue) is `std::vector`, which guarantees a contiguous array of elements.

But as mentioned that behavior is undefined, and there are no guarantees to reproduce that result with a different compiler.

> While if get top value by `auto m = queue.top();`, then output is `3 3 3`.

The value from `top` is stored into `m` once, and never changed afterwards.

Comment: why wouldn't the const reference `m` prolong the return value's lifetime? (because the return type is `const int &` rather than `int`?)

Comment: @stanleyerror In the [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue/top) it's said _"... Returns reference to the top element in the priority queue. This element will be removed on a call to pop()."_

Comment: @stanleyerror you're thinking of when a reference is bound to a prvalue. However `top()` returns an lvalue , not a prvalue (another way to say that is, it returns by reference , not by value). There is no temporary involved.